# Receive an error when attempting to import LDAP (ldif file) with JXplorer

Tags: ldap, novell, edirectory

I want to import a ldif file in my LDAP so i have this error

> javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65
>   - NDS error: no such class (-604)]; remaining name 'o=test'

Thx;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eDirectory error -604 means the objectClass you specified probably has a typo.   (601 is object not found, so the DN is wrong.  609 is Missing Mandatory.  613 is Syntax Violation).

I would suggest that you show the LDIF file you are using so we can try to figure out what you have going on.